# Doctrine2 Batch Update fails with fatal memory error. Trouble with "order by"?

Tags: symfony, batch-file, doctrine-orm

I tried to write a bulk update snippet by following http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results

I use the framework symfony2 and i try to iterate about one million rows to renew my 'slug' column with gedmo doctrine2 extension.

**the code i ended up with:**

```php
$this->container->get('profiler')->disable(); // should disable logging and profiler
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('select a from ACMEArtistBundle:Artist a order by a.touch ASC')
        ->setMaxResults(40); // a.touch is a DateTime Column
$q->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true); // some tipp i read somewhere
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
    $row[0]->setSlug('');
    if (($i % $batchSize) == 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all deletions.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
    ++$i;
}
```

**If i run this code with 256 memory size**, i get this error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /symfony2_installation/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/ArrayHydrator.php on line 230

**If i run this code with 512 memory size**, i get this error with a blank screen: 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

It turned out by removing "order by a.touch ASC" in my SQL, it just works well with more than 2000 entries at once.

One guy in #doctrine mentioned that the one-to-one relationship (self referencing) could be a problem? but removing this relation doesnt solved it.

**Question:** 
How can i mange it? I need to update only the oldest entries in my table.

Comment: Have you tried just doing something like `select a.id` to limit the hydration. I don't think that the one to one relationship *should* be a problem, but it's possible it is.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, i looked at the /app/logs/dev.log and executed the statement sql.
what i found were some chinese signs in the first row (in the name column).

i removed the entry, now the script keeps working... seems to be a problem with the charset. the table is utf8... i wonder where i have to change this charset in the database connection?